# Remove form label when input is active/focus

Tags: css

Trying to remove a icon when the input is active/focused. The problem is that :after do not work. When I click on the input the label is still visible.

Tried with `content: none;` but that didn't work.

```css
#search-label {
 position: relative;
 font-weight: normal;
}

#search-label:before {
 content:"\f002";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 115%;
    position: absolute;
    color: #dddddd;
    top: 5px;
    left: 8px;
}
```

**Edit:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label id="search-label">
        <input id="search-form" class="form-control" placeholder="{% trans "Search" %}" type="text" name="q" value="{{ request.REQUEST.q }}">
    </label>
</div>
```

Can I do this with CSS or do I need JavaScript for this?

**Image of it:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z4i2.jpg

Comment: I think you will need JS for this

Comment: Take a look here: You can't. Content created by :after or :before is not part of the DOM and therefore cannot be selected or modified.
I don't think its possible with css only.

Comment: Will you accept a JS/jQuery solution?

Comment: Alright, how could I use JavaScript for this then?

Comment: Well, what you really need is some HTML to which the CSS applies :). It's not in your snippet. Perhaps you can add it so that everyone can play?

Comment: If you can alter the markup of your form group, a CSS-only solution is possible, by using the immediate sibling selector `+`.

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on your markup, and if you have the freedom and/or ability to modify it.

#### Yes, the markup can be changed: CSS-only solution

If your label is a sibling and occurs after the input, you can toggle its display status based on the state of the input element itself, for example:

```css
.input-row {
  position: relative;
}
.input-row label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.input-row label::before {
  transition: 1s;
  /* Just to show how the toggle works */
}
.input-row label.icon1::before {
  content: 'icon1';
}
.input-row label.icon2::before {
  content: 'icon2';
}
.input-row input {
  padding: 0 2rem 0;
}
.input-row input:focus + label::before,
.input-row input:active + label::before {
  opacity: 0;            /* To visually hide the label's pseudoelement */
  pointer-events: none;  /* To prevent any cursor-based interaction */
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="input-row">
    <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" />
    <label for="input1" class="icon1"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-row">
    <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" />
    <label for="input1" class="icon2"></label>
  </div>
</form>
```

#### No, the markup cannot be changed: JS-only solution

If the markup cannot be changed, you will be forced to use a JS-only solution. This is because CSS does not have the ability to traverse backwards (i.e. select previous siblings) or up the parent node (i.e. select the wrapping elements). Remember that as **pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM, you cannot select them via JS**. Instead, you will have to toggle a class in order to perform the hiding/showing.

In my proof-of-concept example below using the markup that you have provided after updating your question, you can see how jQuery can be used to achieve the desired function. You can of course rewrite the JS function in native JS ;)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.form-group :input')
    .focus(function() {
      $(this).closest('label').addClass('hide');
    })
    .blur(function() {
      $(this).closest('label').removeClass('hide');
    });
});
```

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: normal;
}
label::before {
  content: "icon";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 115%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 8px;
  transition: 1s;        /* Added just to show the effect of toggling opacity */
}
label.hide::before {
  opacity: 0;            /* To visually hide the label's pseudoelement */
  pointer-events: none;  /* To prevent any cursor-based interaction */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label id="search-label">
    <input id="search-form" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text" name="q" value="">
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will find this useful:

```
  $('.form-group')
.focus(function() {
  $(this).prev('label').addClass('u-hidden');
})
.blur(function() {
      n=$(this).val();
     if (n.length<1){
  $(this).prev('label').removeClass('u-hidden');}else{
       $(this).prev('label').addClass('u-hidden');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery solution would look something like this:

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    $("span#your_icon").hide();
}).blur(function(){
    $("span#your_icon").show();
});
```

A JS solution would look like this:

```
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("focus", function(){
    document.getElementById("#your_icon").style.display = 'none';
});

document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("blur", function(){
    document.getElementById("#your_icon").style.display = 'inline';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of label you can use a background image and do somthing like this

```
.input-search {
    background:url('http://www.aljanaedu.com/Limitless/images/icons/14x14/search.png') no-repeat left 10px center;
 }
.input-search:focus {
    background-image:none;
}
```

Working Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ngvs7411/)

Answer (score 0):

albeit a few years late to the question... but I found the best article that worked wonders for me, using jQuery, this article shows us how to essentially add a class to the label's parent container (div) if the input field is either selected/focused AND if the field has a value, OR remove said class if the input field is NOT focused AND empty. https://knowbility.org/blog/2019/animating-form-labels

```
    $("form input").on("blur input focus", function() {
  var $field = $(this).closest(".field");
  if (this.value) {
    $field.addClass("filled");
  } else {
    $field.removeClass("filled");
  }
});

$("form input").on("focus", function() {
  var $field = $(this).closest(".field");
  if (this) {
    $field.addClass("filled");
  } else {
    $field.removeClass("filled");
  }
});
```